# Handler data before return

Tags: php, design-patterns, structure

This is my simple implementation for custom data before return base on data type. 
In case I have many many type I want to know what is the best solutions for route to expected handler function. I don't want to use too much`switch` or `if-else` .Could you guys take a look at this code and tell me any suggestion,  Is there any other way to handler data before return? Thank you

```
function A($data) {

}

function B($data) {
}

function bill($data) {
    return converter($data, $type)
}

function converter($data, $type) {
    if ($type == 'A')
    {
        return A($data);
    } else {
        return B($data);
    }
}
```

p/s my English is not good . Sorry about that.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `return` in your `converter()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`call_user_func()`](https://php.net/call_user_func) to call the function according to `$type`:

```
function A($data) {
    return __function__ . " " . reset($data);
}

function B($data) {
    return __function__ . " " . end($data);
}

function converter($data, $type) {
    if (!function_exists($type)) return false ;
    return call_user_func($type, $data) ;
}

// Example:
echo converter(['data','test'], 'A'); // calls A()
echo converter(['data','test'], 'B'); // calls B()
```

Will outputs :

```
A data
B test
```

You could also take a look to [`call_user_func_array()`](https://php.net/call_user_func_array) for use of an array of parameters.